# php/json - print out json php while loop

Tags: php, json, while-loop

How can I print out data from a while loop with JSON?

Currently, I have this in the `message.php`

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#pmid<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                 type:"GET",
                 url: "/index.php?i=pm&p=rr",
                 dataType:'json',
                 data: {id:"<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>"},
                 success : function(res){
                   if(res){
                    $( "#name").html(res.name); 
                    $( "#post").html(res.response);
                   }
                 }
            });
          });

        </script>
<span id="name"></span>
                <ul id="post">

                </ul>
```

And in the `get.php` file, I have this:

```
$name=$getUser['username'];



while($postData=mysql_fetch_assoc($postsql)){
 $post = '<li>
   <img width="30" height="30" src="images/avatar-male.jpg">
   <div class="bubble">
     <a class="user-name" href="">123</a>
     <p class="message">
       '.$postData['text'].'
     </p>
     <p class="time">

     </p>
   </div>
 </li>';
}

$arrRet = array();
$arrRet['name'] = $name;
$arrRet['post'] = $post;
echo json_encode($arrRet); 
die();
```

So far, the $name value is working. I can print that out to `#name`. I just can't figure out how to print out the $post while loop to `#post`

Comment: If you are going to downvote the least you can do is leave a comment and explain to the OP where he is going wrong!

Comment: @Paddyd, I suggested this in another SO group. I was downvoted out of existance and the only explanation was that downvoters like to remain anonymous and offer no help what-so-ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your MySQL results into an array and then make json with this

then in your JavaScript code you prints your data (post) with a for/foreach loop

your `Get.php`  should like this :

```
$name=$getUser['username'];

$result = array();

while($postData=mysql_fetch_assoc($postsql)){
    $result[] = $postData['text'];
}

$arrRet = array();
$arrRet['name'] = $name;
$arrRet['post'] = $result;
echo json_encode($arrRet);
die();
```

and `message.php` :

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#pmid<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                 type:"GET",
                 url: "/index.php?i=pm&p=rr",
                 dataType:'json',
                 data: {id:"<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>"},
                 success : function(res){
                   if(res){
                    $( "#name").html(res.name); 
                    var posts = res.post;

                    for(var i in posts)
                    {
                        var post = '<li><img width="30" height="30" src="images/avatar-male.jpg"><div class="bubble">
                                    <a class="user-name" href="">123</a><p class="message">'
                                    + posts[i] +
                                    '</p><p class="time"></p></div></li>';
                        $( "#post").append(post);
                    }

                   }
                 }
            });
          });

        </script>
<span id="name"></span>
      <ul id="post">

      </ul>
```

Good luck